# code cells do not collapse after export to html with TOC

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tend to use this code and package to make code cells collapsible and share output of a notebook as HTML with TOC:

```
library(IRdisplay)

display_html(
'

<script>  
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
  if (code_show){
    $(\'div.input\').hide();
  } else {
    $(\'div.input\').show();
  }
  code_show = !code_show
}  
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
  <form action="javascript:code_toggle()">
    <input type="submit" value="Code On/Off">
 </form>

<style type="text/css">

.container { width:80% !important; }

.main-container {
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/*body{font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode} */

.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #004F59;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #004F59;
}

.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:focus, .list-group-item.active:hover {
    background-color: #004F59;
}
</style>

'
)
```

I recently had to switch machines/laptops and although this still works when run inside Jupyter the exported HTHL + TOC shows the code and the depicted button is not responsive (i.e. does not collapse the code cells). I am trying to isolate the problem. What could be the reason for this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: Your example HTML does not contain any data. Only script and style information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use:

```
pip install nbconvert==5.6.1
```

and NOT Anaconda. Never got it to work with Anaconda but only with separate Python.